# wfc data - Strange behaviour after getting data from database

Tags: windows-8, odata, microsoft-metro

I'm learning how to connect win8 metro app with azure sql database. I've created .net web form application where I've created Entity Model and WFC Data Service. 
From tutorial I was watching I should be receive data from url http://domain.com:52034/ServiceName.svc/User

When I start this service via VisualStudio (http://domain.com:52034/ServiceName.svc) I get xml with configuration and my collection name (User). When I type the first Url I get question do I want to subscribe to the subscription channel o.O I'm not getting my collection data. 
When I type http://domain.com:52034/ServiceName.svc/User(1) I'm not getting the user with uid = 1 but I'm getting page not found. What am I doing wrong ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution.

First of all big plus for you Vitek. Thanks to your advice I could read xml properly

Secondly I had to add: config.UseVerboseErrors=true;
After that everything started to work.

About question in my comment. While configuring datamodel connection there is an option to set that login and pass are send with the request.

Best regards,
Dawid

Answer (score 1):

If you target your browser to ~/User the service responds with application/atom+xml;type=feed which is recognized by most browsers as ATOM feed (as it should) and the browser tries to be "Easy to use" and either show it in a different view or asks you to subscribe. In IE you can turn this off by going to Internet Options -> Content -> Feeds and Web Slices -> Settings -> Turn on feed reading view. Make sure that check box is not checked. Then reopen the URL in question in a new tab and it should show you the raw XML. (That will only work in the desktop IE). I would think you can do the same in other browsers as well, I just don't know the specifics.
You can try it also on the sample services for example on http://services.odata.org/OData/OData.svc/Products.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the tip. It helped that I don`t get rss questions but I get error 500. Can it be cause wrong data or something ? How should I send user and password ? Maybe this is my mistake ?